# Logistic regression model with continuous and categorical variables

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I have a dataset “ex” with categorical and continuous variables. The response variable is A16. I want to build a logistic regression model but I receive a message:

glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

and I suspect that there is something wring with the dataset structure. Although I understand that factors should not be a problem for GLM models in R.
Here is the dataset:

```
   A1    A2     A3 A4 A5 A6 A7     A8 A9 A10 A11 A12 A13      A14  A15 A16
68  b 19.42  6.500  u  g  w  h  1.460  t   t   7   f   g  80.0000 2954   1
69  b 35.17 25.125  u  g  x  h  1.625  t   t   1   t   g 515.0000  500   1
70  b 32.33  7.500  u  g  e bb  1.585  t   f   0   t   s 420.0000    0   0
71  b 34.83  4.000  u  g  d bb 12.500  t   f   0   t   g 280.2858    0   0
72  a 38.58  5.000  u  g cc  v 13.500  t   f   0   t   g 980.0000    0   0
73  b 44.25  0.500  u  g  m  v 10.750  t   f   0   f   s 400.0000    0   0
74  b 44.83  7.000  y  p  c  v  1.625  f   f   0   f   g 160.0000    2   0
75  b 20.67  5.290  u  g  q  v  0.375  t   t   1   f   g 160.0000    0   0
76  b 34.08  6.500  u  g aa  v  0.125  t   f   0   t   g 443.0000    0   0
77  a 19.17  0.585  y  p aa  v  0.585  t   f   0   t   g 160.0000    0   0
78  b 21.67  1.165  y  p  k  v  2.500  t   t   1   f   g 180.0000   20   0
data.frame':    11 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ A1 : Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ A2 : num  19.4 35.2 32.3 34.8 38.6 ...
 $ A3 : num  6.5 25.1 7.5 4 5 ...
 $ A4 : Factor w/ 3 levels "l","u","y": 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 3 ...
 $ A5 : Factor w/ 3 levels "g","gg","p": 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 ...
 $ A6 : Factor w/ 14 levels "aa","c","cc",..: 13 14 5 4 3 10 2 11 1 1 ...
 $ A7 : Factor w/ 9 levels "bb","dd","ff",..: 4 4 1 1 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
 $ A8 : num  1.46 1.62 1.58 12.5 13.5 ...
 $ A9 : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ A10: Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ A11: int  7 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ A12: Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ A13: Factor w/ 3 levels "g","p","s": 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ A14: num  80 515 420 280 980 ...
 $ A15: int  2954 500 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 ...
 $ A16: num  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

dput(ex)
structure(list(A1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), A2 = c(19.42, 
35.17, 32.33, 34.83, 38.58, 44.25, 44.83, 20.67, 34.08, 19.17, 
21.67), A3 = c(6.5, 25.125, 7.5, 4, 5, 0.5, 7, 5.29, 6.5, 0.585, 
1.165), A4 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("l", "u", "y"), class = "factor"), A5 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("g", "gg", 
"p"), class = "factor"), A6 = structure(c(13L, 14L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
10L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 9L), .Label = c("aa", "c", "cc", "d", "e", 
"ff", "i", "j", "k", "m", "q", "r", "w", "x"), class = "factor"), 
    A7 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L), .Label = c("bb", "dd", "ff", "h", "j", "n", "o", "v", 
    "z"), class = "factor"), A8 = c(1.46, 1.625, 1.585, 12.5, 
    13.5, 10.75, 1.625, 0.375, 0.125, 0.585, 2.5), A9 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("f", 
    "t"), class = "factor"), A10 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("f", "t"), class = "factor"), 
    A11 = c(7L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), A12 = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("f", 
    "t"), class = "factor"), A13 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("g", "p", "s"), class = "factor"), 
    A14 = c(80, 515, 420, 280.285801010101, 980, 400, 160, 160, 
    443, 160, 180), A15 = c(2954L, 500L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 20L), A16 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    )), row.names = 68:78, class = "data.frame")
```

And here is the code for the model:

```
fitex1 <- glm(A16~., data=ex_train, family=binomial)
fitex0 <- glm(A16~1, data=ex_train, family=binomial)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in `fitex0`? Also, that error message typically means that your model is experiencing [separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_(statistics))/[complete separation](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/), which has been addressed on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression).

Comment: thank you Wil. I have added the requested information to the post. I am building a constant model for the fitex0.

Comment: See my comments above about complete separation. I'm not sure if this is a sample of your data or the whole dataset, but in the sample you have provided there are more variable than observations, so the problem will not be tractable because you don't have enough degrees of freedom. And if it is representative of your larger dataset many of the variables have extremely low variance (i.e. they are nearly constant), which can be problematic in small samples.